# Swift method parameters in documentation

Tags: swift

I sometimes see Swift methods documented as `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` or `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`. Where are these generalised method documentation conventions documented? For example: where can I see what the underscore means, how to interpret multiple method parameters documented in this fashion, etc.

Comment: type func tableView and let Xcode auto complete it for you. It will show all variants including cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Yes, I can and do do that but I'd like to know how to properly read the generalised documentation using the convention described above.  This is not a question about tableView or any specific method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is illustrated in [*The Swift Programming Language: Functions*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158). This is the external signature of the function, i.e. what you need to know in order to call it. It consists of the function name, plus all of the argument labels for all of the parameters of that function.

Consider

```
func greet(person: String) -> String {
    ...
}
```

This is the `greet(person:)` function.

But consider the following, slightly more complicated, Swift 3 [`UITableViewDataSource`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ...
}
```

Here, each of these two parameters has both an argument label (what is used when the function is called) followed by a parameter name (what is used to refer to that parameter inside the function itself). In this case, the first parameter has no argument label (designated by `_`), but the name is `tableView`. The second parameter's argument label is `cellForRowAt`, and the name is `indexPath`.

In this case, you'll see the above `UITableViewDataSource` method referenced as [`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview): The function name is `tableView`, the first parameter has no argument label (designated by `_`), and the second parameter has an argument label of `cellForRowAt`.

---

As an aside, in Swift version 2, the first parameter's argument label would default to `_` (i.e. no label) unless explicitly specified otherwise. Effective Swift 3, the first parameter works the same all of the other parameters, defaulting to whatever the parameter name was (which is why you'll see `_` explicitly referenced in this case, to explicitly specify that this Swift 3 function's first parameter doesn't have a label).

Comment: (I couldn't find `Swift gives the first parameter name in` following that link, even continuing to [Function Argument Labels and Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID166) didn't help.)

Comment: Yes, that was behavior unique to Swift 2, where the first parameter behaved differently that all the subsequent labels. This is an anachronism, dating back to Objective-C, which was retired in Swift 3, which is why you don't see this referenced in that document anymore.